# Problems running javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, embed, playsound

I have a ASP.NET application that plays a sequence of sounds. I call the javascript function in onload() event from my Default.aspx page:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), 
  "playSound", "playSound()", true);
```

This is my function js:

```
function playSound() 
{

document.getElementById("span_alerta").innerHTML ="<embed src='Music/hs.wav' 
  hidden=false autostart=true loop=false playcount=3>";
}
```

My application uses a timerRefresh 1 in 1 minute, and the event tick () execute the onload (). Every time I start my application, it does not run my sound, however, after running the TICK () the sound plays.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you try to give "" for html atributes.and add return false in fn calling statements.

Comment: That sounds just right: "after running the tick the sound plays". Timer events do not fire upon page load or timer load, only after the timer spent its designated time.